# how to show relationship data in human readable text in flask-admin page

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-admin

My admin page, [see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQWvD.png),
when I want to edit User, I see that Serv - `orm.relation("Services", back_populates='user')` shows in non-human readable text.
This is my model:

```
class User(SqlAlchemyBase, UserMixin, SerializerMixin):
  __tablename__ = 'users'
  id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
  ..
  serv = orm.relation("Services", back_populates='user')

  def __repr__(self):
    return self.name
```

What function I have to include?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined either a `__repr__` method or `__str__` method for your `Services` model.

See this SO QA, [Difference between **str** and **repr**?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2626364/2800058). Note the summary in the answer:

> Implement `__repr__` for any class you implement. This should be second
> nature. Implement `__str__` if you think it would be useful to have a
> string version which errs on the side of readability.